# Doodle jump help in unity3d c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am facing a relatively easy yet important problem with unity. My situation is as follows:

I am making a doodle jump game where I have programmed a prefab monster to move from right to left. Currently the player dies when he is not seen by the camera but I also need him to die when he touches the monster. When he dies I only need a panel with a retry button to appear, no objects need to be destroyed.

The code:

```
public GameObject panel;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Spawn") 
        {
            panel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

please help me make the panel appear when he touches the monster. The panel is a prefab, I think that this may be a problem, but if it is not a prefab it doesn't want to assign to the public gameobject, please make the panel appear when the player touches the monster!

Comment: this code that you wrote here it doesn't work?

Comment: set `IsTrigger` to `false`

Comment: when the monster colides with the player the panel in the game doesn't appear, but when i stop the game then it appears

Comment: it is to set to false

Comment: put a `Debug.log` in your `OnCollisionEnter` check if it gets called

Comment: i made this, it get's called everytime, it works when debug.log, whe nthe player and the monster collides the debug.log appears in the console

Comment: i ahve tried, the debug works

Comment: so your panel doesn't get activated?but your code reaches inside if

Comment: no, it doesn't, may be you want to check through teaam viewer?

Comment: maybe you deactivate it from another script

Comment: use this code and check if Active is written in console`if (col.gameObject.tag == "Spawn") 
    {
        panel.SetActive(true);if (panel.activeSelf)
    Debug.log ("Active");
    }`

Comment: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {
 public GameObject panel;
 public void PlayButton()
 {
  Application.LoadLevel (1);
 }
 void Start()
 {
  if(panel.gameObject.activeInHierarchy == true)
  {
   panel.gameObject.SetActive(false);
  }
 }

}

Comment: it is in `Start` it only gets called once this wont make any problem , did you check with the code I posted

Comment: man, i have tried, in colso writes active but the panel doesn''t appear

Comment: wha tshould i do, this seems inposible!

Comment: click on the panel pause the game and take a screenshot after `OnCollisionEnter` is called and post it here

Comment: ok, i am doing it now

Comment: and maybe your panel is a child of another object and that object is inactive so even when you activate your panel because the parent is deactivated your panel wont show up

Comment: man, how to upload a photo, please cna you verify through team viewre yes,it is a child but the parent is active, please can you check through team viewer?

Comment: http://prnt.sc/aylhr4

Comment: is this code  `using System.Collections; using UnityEngine.UI; using UnityEngine.EventSystems; public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour { public GameObject panel; public void PlayButton() { Application.LoadLevel (1); } void Start() { if(panel.gameObject.activeInHierarchy == true) { panel.gameObject.SetActive(false); } } }` attached to your panel?

Comment: no, it is attached to the child of the panel which is a button, it is a try again button

Comment: child of this panel ? right?the panel you want to activate?

Comment: to the panel is attached one script and to the player too the dsame script

Comment: yes child of this panel

Comment: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Invisible : MonoBehaviour {
 public GameObject panel;

  void Update() 
 {
  Vector2 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
  if (screenPosition.y > Screen.height || screenPosition.y < 0)
  {
   panel.SetActive(true);
  }
   }
 }

Comment: this code is attached to panel

Comment: and it works when the player is done what of the camera view , the panel appears but when it collides with monster it doesn't appear

Comment: delete this part of the code `void Start() { if(panel.gameObject.activeInHierarchy == true) { panel.gameObject.SetActive(false); } } ` then test

Comment: man, thanks you very much, i have deleted the panel from prefabs and have attached the script to the player not to the monster, nad i said when player colide with monster then panel active and it works, thnak you very much!

Comment: it was disabling it right after you enabled it because start is called after enabling

Comment: ok, thnaks,  i will have more problems with this projet and i iwll ask my questions here, thnaks you!

Comment: no problem , good luck

Comment: thanks! the same to you!